# Макросы идентификации архитектуры

Tags: gcc, c, c++, linux

Какие макросы в Linux позволяют во время компиляции определить тип архитектуры, для которой осуществляется компиляция: х86 или х86_64 ?

Или более расширено. Имеются, положим, две ассемблерные вставки: одна для х86, другая для х86_64. Нужно произвести условную компиляцию, ориентируясь на конечную архитектуру исполняемого файла. Как это можно сделать, какие макросы это позволяют?

Comment: Может `__x86_64/__x86_64__` против `__i386/__386__,__i486/__i486__`? (cpp -dM -m32 a.h)

Comment: Спасибо, это тоже правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это зависит от [компилятора](http://predef.sourceforge.net/prearch.html). Для GCC это, например, `__amd64__`.

```
#ifdef __amd64__
// x64
#else
// x86
#endif
```

Comment: Спасибо, а какой макрос для определения х86 ?

Comment: Для x86 - макрос `__i386__` (там же по ссылке).

Answer (score 1):

Хм.. а если компилятор не предоставляет макросов для определения архитектуры системы, возможно получится воспользоваться чем-то подобным ?

```
#if __SIZEOF_LONG__ == 4
#define ARCH_32
#else
#define ARCH_64
#endif
```

Должно работать, впрочем, может быть надежнее использовать не LONG, но сути не меняет.

Comment: Ну, нет гарантированной корреляции между архитектурой и размером long int. На PC, скорее всего, пройдет, но вот переносимость очень сомнительная.